# Why do my markers end up at the top left corner if I navigate back via ajax?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, jquery-mobile

When using a Google Map on a page in http://jquerymobile.com; if one navigates away and then back to the map page all the markers end up at the top left corner.

Example:

[image: Google Maps with jQuery marker problem.]

The start of my jQuery JavaScript snippet:

```
$('.page-map').live('pageinit', function() {
...do stuff.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change 'pageinit' to 'pageshow':

```
$('.page-map').live('pageshow', function() {
...do stuff.
}
```